# Insert into MySQL "on duplicate key update" syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, sql-insert

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO couponentries (itemid, coupon, MSISDN, channel, result) 
       VALUES ('".$itemid."','".$CouponCode."', '".$MSISDN."','".$channel."','".$status."')
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE couponentries.result = VALUES('Invalid couponcode[ERR: Already exists]')";
```

I am trying to insert new item from PHP webform to MySQL database. If I insert a duplicate row I will make the result update to an error message. Here is my code. It keeps giving me a syntax error.

> ERROR: Could not able to execute You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Invalid couponcode[ERR: Already exists]')' at line 3

Comment: `... UPDATE couponentries.result = 'Invalid couponcode[ERR: Already exists]'`

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not the right tool for what you are trying. I' afraid - it's not possible at all. You just can not insert a duplicate.

Comment: @PaulSpiegl is it possible to insert a duplicate if just one field is the same but the rest fields are all different? Here, in this case, it's just the same coupon. is it still able to do that?

Comment: It depends on the unique key(s). Post your table schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE couponentries`).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks! I removed the unique key constraint. However, it still doesn't update the error message to the new duplicate entry. The struggle is real!

Comment: I never told, removing the unique key constraint would be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a string literal to update your column - lose the `values`:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO couponentries (itemid, coupon, MSISDN, channel, result) 
       VALUES ('".$itemid."','".$CouponCode."', '".$MSISDN."','".$channel."','".$status."')
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE couponentries.result = 'Invalid couponcode[ERR: Already exists]'";
```

Obligatory side note:
Concatinating strings like this makes your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should probably look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.